# Is there any way to get a listview overscroll on Android 2.2 or 2.1?

Tags: android

Is there any way to get a listview overscroll on Android 2.2 or 2.1?

I have used overscroll in Android 2.3 but its not running in 2.2. How can I achieve that?

Comment: See [link](https://github.com/Larphoid/android-Overscroll-ListView) for an example of this...

Answer (score 0):

Create an "overscroll" view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
  <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="320px"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

You need some global variables in the main activity:

```
private int currentScrollState = OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
// itemAtTop and itemOffset are needed for when the listview doesn't have enough items to fill the screen
private int itemAtTop = 0, itemOffset = 0; // reset both to 0 each time you populate the listview
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

In main activity's onCreate, before setting the listview's adapter, add header and footer:

```
View v        = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.listview_overscrollview, null);
listview.addHeaderView(v, null, false);
listview.addFooterView(v, null, false);
listview.setOnScrollListener(this);
```

Your main activity has to override 2 methods because of the setOnScrollListener:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
{
    checkTopAndBottom();
}


@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
{
    currentScrollState = scrollState;
    checkTopAndBottom();
}
```

The checkTopAndBottom() function, which should also be called after the listview is (re)populated:

```
public void checkTopAndBottom()
{
    if ( listview.getCount() <= 2 ) return;  // do nothing, only header and footer in listview
    if ( scrollState != OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE ) return; // do nothing, listview still scrolling
    if ( listview.getFirstVisiblePosition() < 1 ) {
        listview.setSelectionFromTop(1, -1);
    }
    if ( listview.getLastVisiblePosition() == listview.getCount()-1 ) {
        listview.setSelectionFromTop(listview.getCount()-1, listview.getHeight());
    }
    mHandler.post(checkListviewBottom);
}
```

And finally the runnable ( for the listview.getFirstVisiblePosition(), etc to be up to date ):

```
private final Runnable checkListviewBottom = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if ( listview.getLastVisiblePosition() == listview.getCount()-1 ) {
            if ( itemAtTop == 0 ) {
                if ( listview.getFirstVisiblePosition() <= 1 ) {
                    itemAtTop  = 1;
                    itemOffset = -1;
                } else {
                    itemAtTop  = listview.getCount()-1;
                    itemOffset = listview.getHeight()+1;
                }
            }
            if ( itemAtTop == listview.getCount()-1 || (itemAtTop == 1 && listview.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0) ) {
                listview.setSelectionFromTop(itemAtTop, itemOffset);
            }
        }
    }
};
```